# Cloud infrastructure term for services like AWS Sagemaker, Google Colaboratory, Microsoft Azure ML Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, platform-as-a-service

There are multiple `* as a service` terms in cloud computing <sup>[[1](https://www.optimizely.com/insights/blog/pizza-as-a-service/), [2](https://gist.github.com/alvations/89d65a80ff8caec038552843dea89f37#cloud-infrastructure)]</sup>, e.g.

- Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS)
- Platform as a Service (PaaS)
- Software as a Service (SaaS)

But when it comes to data-related and Jupyter notebook related platforms like,

- AWS Sagemaker,
- Google Colaboratory,
- Microsoft Azure ML Studio

Where do they fall on the "Pizza" spectrum? And is there a canonical term for these "Jupyter as a service"?

Comment: Also asked on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170183/147895 but the community thinks it's not applicable on webapps...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term for these is "MLOps".

They are really a specialized kind of platform as a service, so they're comparable to PaaS on the pizza scale.